# Agitator problem whirlpool topload washer; spin ok

Tags: washing-machine, washer

LSB6300PW4 Washer fills, starts agitating, then after a minute or 2 it stops agitating and there's a burning smell. When it stops agitating I continue hearing a click/ticking noise behind timer. If I advance the timer to rinse/spin it resumes normal activity and finishes from that point. Please advise could this be the coupler or the motor itself? Thank you! Lynn

Comment: Maybe you need a new timer or control module, there is a defect in the circuits.

Comment: Sounds to me like the timer has gone.